# Button won't redirect to given html page in location.href

Tags: javascript, html, button, href

I can't redirect to the next page. Please help me. I have a project due tomorrow. I've been trying for more than five hours. Please help me. I'm begging you guys. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I'm very new to Javascript.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong

```js
document.getElementById("one").onclick = function() {
  location.href = "lessons.html"
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> MaxFluency Tutorials Page</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="tutorial.css">


  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="topbar">
      <center>
        <p> Tutorials</p>
      </center>
  </header>
  </div>

  <div class="lessons">
    <center>
      <button class=les id=one type="button"> <h3> Lesson 1: </h3> Nature of Communication </button>
      <button class=les id="2nd"> <h3>Lesson 2:</h3></button>
      <button class="les" id="3rd"> <h3>Lesson 3:</h3></button>
    </center>
  </div>

  <div class="nav">

    <center><button class="loc"> Home</button>
      <button class="loc"> Highscores </button>
      <button class="loc"> Support us!</button>
    </center>

  </div>

  <script type="text/Javascript" src="tutorials.js">

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You have some badly formatted html. For example `class=les id=one` should be `class="les" id="one"`.

Comment: @Gavin Quotes are not required for attribute values that don't contain special characters.

Comment: what is path for lessons.html?  what's the url for the website?  What's this suppose to do:    <script type="text/Javascript" src="tutorials.js">

  </script>

Comment: You just have a lot of html syntax errors that need fixing.

Comment: I made tutorials.js as the external file for the html one. Lessons.html is where it's supposed to redirected to

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is quite malformed, with some opening tags not closed anywhere, closing tags that do not have any matching tag, etc... This needs some tidying.

Also, if this Javascript code is in an external file, make sure it is wrapped in an `onload` event (making sure that all HTML elements actually loaded before calling `document.getElementById`). Finally, note the semicolon placement. You should place the semicolon after the statement, not after the function's ending `}`!

Side note: Why re-inventing the wheel when you can simply use an anchor tag (`<a>`) for redirecting?

```js
onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("one").onclick = function () {
    console.log("clicked!");
    location.href = "lessons.html";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> MaxFluency Tutorials Page</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="tutorial.css">

    </head>
  <body>
  <header>
    <div class="topbar">
      <center> <p> Tutorials</p> </center> 
     </div>
  </header> <!-- this closing tag was missing -->

    <div class="lessons">
      <center>    
        <button class=les id=one type="button" > <h3> Lesson 1: </h3> Nature of Communication </button>
         <button class=les id="2nd"> <h3>Lesson 2:</h3></button>
         <button class="les" id="3rd"> <h3>Lesson 3:</h3></button>
       </center> 
    </div> 

   <div class="nav">

         <center><button class="loc"> Home</button>
           <button class="loc"> Highscores </button>
               <button class="loc"> Support us!</button>
           </center> 

   </div>  

     <script type="text/Javascript" src="tutorials.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Yumolb note that I assumed the Javascript code (above)  is present inside a JS file. Add the Javascript code to one of your JS files, e.g. tutorials.js

Answer (score 0):

1) there is a lonely closing script tag in the head section.

2) your closing header and div tags before .lessons are in reverse order

3) Here is a fiddle that seems to be working. Button goes to a 404 just because the lessons.html doesn't exist here.

I also added a slash for a relative path. I assume you are probably working from a single root directory given that it is a tutorial but I could be wrong there.

```
location.href = "/lessons.html";
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y7txje5c/1/

Comment: lessons.html is an html file I created yeah. Well, I copied the code written down there from an earlier answer to Visual Studio Code but it won't work. I was surprised when you tried it and it worked. I don't know why this is happening. I can't breathe from all the tension now.

Comment: Just out of curiosity...what does your file structure look like? Is your js file even importing?

Comment: Well, I save my js file from VS code to my notes folder but I don't exactly know how importing works? Well, I put the script tag as the last tag in the body?

Comment: so assuming you have a notes folder you would need to include that in your src attribute.  <script type="text/Javascript" src="/notes/tutorials.js"></script>

Comment: turns out it works. But when I saved it from visual studio code, it didn't. I don't know why